# Render problem en archivo content.xml, linea tools:showIn no encuentra mi archivo app_bar.xml

Tags: android-layout

El problema que tengo es el siguiente:

> Render Problem
>   The surrounding layout (@layout/app_bar_servicios) did not actually
>   include this layout. Remove tools:showIn=... from the root tag.

He verificado que `app_bar_servicios.xml` efectivamente se encuentra en la misma ruta (res/layout/) con el archivo `content_servicios.xml` y `activity_servicios.xml`

Debo agregar el `app_bar` porque tengo ahí un pequeño diseño, pero no logro resolver este problema.

Este es mi archivo `content_servicios.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ServiciosActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_servicios">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Una posible solución que encontré es hacer la siguiente modificación

```
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_servicios"
```

por

```
tools:showIn="activity_servicios"
```

Eso hace que el error desaparezca pero obviamente no podré utilizar el diseño del `app_bar`.

Utilizo

```
Android Studio 3.4.1
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
y Windows 10 10.0
```

Ojalá que podáis ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me pasó algo parecido al intentar diseñar un navigationDrawer. No sé si es el caso, pero prueba a incluir una etiqueta include dentro de tu Constraint a ver qué pasa. Sería algo así como:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ServiciosActivity">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_servicios"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Si tengo agregado el include, tal cual. Pero aún asi el problema se da